# Ubuntu offerered way back when a list of 3d party software, can I still find that today?

Tags: software-installation, software-sources

I remember, I think it was Ubuntu 10.x, there was an amazing app that showed every 3d party app you could possibly install with a Linux OS from Blender to Vine. It had an icon of the software and a description of what it did and one click and it was installed, no packages to upload no terminal typing. I really liked that feature.

Does such a thing exist today?

Comment: Are you looking for the Software Center? Or maybe Synaptic?

Comment: Check out the App Grid from the Ubuntu MATE project. http://www.appgrid.org/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's Synaptic, which is mainly a visualized version of apt command.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto

Comment: It didn't look like Synaptic, it look more like what addons look like in Firefox, large icon on the left description in the middle and install button on the right.